# What words exist that come from deconstructed characters?

Tags: characters, word

Page 178 of《成都话方言词典》has the following entry:

[image]

> 丘八儿 qiū bér
>   [tɕ‘iəu⁵⁵ pər²¹] 丘八, 旧时称军人。因“丘”加“八”为“兵”而得名(含贬义)。

丘八 is a deconstruction of the character 兵.

What words exist that come from deconstructed characters?

Comment: I presume you are asking only entries in dictionary, right? Or else you can break down thousands of characters and make similar two characters terms out of them

Comment: One deconstructed characters case come to my mind, it is '虫二' which are 風月 without the surrounding parts,  '虫二' is a word play for "風月無邉" (endless romance)

Comment: @TangHo I'm just asking for words **in use**, or used before in the past, they don't have to be included in any dictionaries. Obviously I could break down characters myself and give them meaning but that would defeat the purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

look for "拆字" (roughly destruct character), particularly fortune telling story.

水巷 --> 港

卯金刀 --> 劉

several verses from a famous oracle poem in hong kong, 1933:

"人我太陽爭北土"

**人我**　--> **俄**羅斯 (russia)

"十四一心人發奮．水去西方啟戰爭"

**十四一心人** --> **德**國 (third reich, at that era)

**水去**

"晉有出頭寧坐視．中央生草不堪耘"

**晉有出頭**

**中央生草**

guess these five characters?

edited.

another word to look for is "離合", there're many examples in literary of yore. e.g. the wiki had [古今譚槩, in volume 29, "談資部"](https://zh.wikisource.org/wiki/%E5%8F%A4%E4%BB%8A%E8%AD%9A%E6%A7%A9/29):

> 「取上一字，下拆兩字，字義相協。」倡云：「山上有明光，不知是日光、月光。」文云：「堂上掛珠簾，不知是王家的、朱家的。」陳云：「有客到舘驛，不知是舍人、官人。」王云：「半夜生孩兒，不知是子時、亥時。」各賞大觥。

in which the condition is choose one character (取上一字), break it into two (下拆兩字), and then the character, its meaning is in accord (字義相協).

four persons done it :)

山上有明光，不知是日光、月光 (**明 --> 日, 月**)

堂上掛珠簾，不知是王家的、朱家的 (**珠 --> 王, 朱**)

有客到舘驛，不知是舍人、官人 (**舘 --> 舍, 官**)

半夜生孩兒，不知是子時、亥時 (**孩 --> 子, 亥**)

it might be too difficult for elementary learners, or simplified chinese users. but, it's the funny, witty aspect of the traditional culture.

Comment: 人我 should be Russia?

Comment: yes, you get it, 4 left :)

Comment: Quite appropriate poems given the 1940s I suppose. Think I got them all.

Comment: Is 十四一心人 the character 德?

Comment: get it, 3 left :)

Comment: @drooooze, it was made in 1933, , was on newspaper. great, if you got this five. want to guess the "future"? there're verses which supposed "not-yet-happened-events".

Comment: If they're any more difficult than 晉有出頭 I probably can't get it.......that one was tough. Post it up, I'm curious to see what it is.

Comment: i believe in "delayed gratification". turn your mind engine :) if no-one guess it, i 'll give the "answer", after, 28 hours from now.

Comment: I meant I'm curious to see the "future" verses :) I've gotten all the ones you put up there currently. I was just saying that 晉有出頭 was quite difficult to get (but I got it at the end).

Comment: oops, i'm sorry. i'll post it in a new question, cause it's a long one. wait :)

Comment: ok, done, have a look, particularly part ii of the poem: https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/30235/how-to-interpret-the-oracle-poem-諸葛武侯乩文/30236#30236