# How to interpret the oracle poem (諸葛武侯乩文)?

Tags: cantonese, poetry, hong-kong

Again, referring to [another thread](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/30227/what-words-exist-that-come-from-deconstructed-characters), I made this question, and provided info as an answer.

Have fun destruct character (拆字), or extrasensory perception (觸機)

Here's a version of the oracle poem in wiki:

[https://zh.wikisource.org/zh-hant/諸葛武侯乩文](https://zh.wikisource.org/zh-hant/%E8%AB%B8%E8%91%9B%E6%AD%A6%E4%BE%AF%E4%B9%A9%E6%96%87)

So, how to interpret it?

Answer (score 4):

in the year 1933, a taoist style planchette writing (扶乩) was done at 蓬瀛仙館, in hong kong; for the purpose of asking divine revelation.

the poem contained two parts, part i:

天數茫茫不可知．鸞台暫說各生知

世界干戈終爆發．鼠尾牛頭發現時

此次戰禍非小可．鳶飛魚躍也愁眉

天下生靈西復東．可憐遍地是哀鴻

刀填溝壑無人拾．血染山川滿地紅

天下重武不重文．那怪環球亂紛紛

人我太陽爭北土．美人東渡海波生

十四一心人發奮．水去西方啟戰爭

晉有出頭寧坐視．中央生草不堪耘

切齒仇讎今始復．堅固金城一旦傾

除非攜手馬先生．馬騰四海似蘇秦

遊說辯才世罕有．掉他三寸舌風生

得與聯軍說事因．東人首肯易調停

青天白日由西落．五色旗幟向東生

二蔣雙爭一蔣傷．兩陳相遇一陳亡

東土不知西土樂．五羊風雨見悲傷

水巷仍須是樂邦．諸生不用走忙忙

錢財散去猶小事．性命安全謝上蒼

今宵略說言和語．留與明宵說短長

it was published on the newspaper: [香港工商日報, 15th december 1939](https://mmis.hkpl.gov.hk/coverpage/-/coverpage/view?_coverpage_WAR_mmisportalportlet_hsf=%E9%A6%99%E6%B8%AF%E5%B7%A5%E5%95%86%E6%97%A5%E5%A0%B1&_coverpage_WAR_mmisportalportlet_actual_q=%28%20all_dc.title%3A%28%22%E9%A6%99%E6%B8%AF%E5%B7%A5%E5%95%86%E6%97%A5%E5%A0%B1%22%29%29%20AND+%28%20verbatim_dc.collection%3A%28%22Old%5C%20HK%5C%20Newspapers%22%29%29&_coverpage_WAR_mmisportalportlet_sort_field=dc.publicationdate_bsort&p_r_p_-1078056564_c=QF757YsWv5%2BwYVV8BOODtYtZNUXlAsGW&_coverpage_WAR_mmisportalportlet_o=16&_coverpage_WAR_mmisportalportlet_sort_order=desc&_coverpage_WAR_mmisportalportlet_filter=dc.publicationdate_dt%3A%5B1930-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z+TO+1939-12-31T15%3A59%3A59Z%5D)

[image]

here's part ii:

紅日落完白日落．五星燦爛文明國

中山傾頹草木殃．豺狼虎豹同一鑊

兩重火土甚光明．士農工商皆有作

木子楊花真武興．小小天罡何足論

強反弱兮弱反強．王氣金陵黯然盡

故都陜地聚英華．文物衣冠頭尚白

氣運南方出豪傑．克定中原謀統一

佳人絕色自西來．弄權竊國氣驕逸

狐兔成群功狗烹．倒亂君臣誰與匹

太陽沉去霧雲收．萬國低頭拜彌勒

治亂循環有定時．根樹生枝惟四七

老人星出現南方．紀念化為公正堂

西南獨立曇花現．飛虎潛龍勢莫當

聯軍東指成一氣．劍仙俠士有奇秘

水能剋火火無功．炮火飛機何處避

此是陰陽造化機．土意發明成絕技

稱雄東土日己終．物歸原主非奇事

此時國恥一齊消．四海昇平多吉兆

異術殺人不用刀．偃武修文日月高

三教聖人同住世．群魔妖怪豈能逃

可嘆草頭燒不盡．野外春風吹又生

宮門拔劍除奸佞．白頭變作赤頭人

田間再出華盛頓．造福人群是真命

此人原是紫微星．定國安民功德盛

執中守一正乾坤．巍巍蕩蕩希堯舜

百年世事不勝悲．誠恐諸君不及見

好脩功果待來生．將相公侯前世善

或是星辰下界來．或是神仙搖一變

或是前生因果大．當然轉世功名顯

山人復對諸生談．續上前文同一線

千年萬載事悠悠．縱使神仙難預算

略將一二說君知．酬答諸生還了願

山人告別返西川．來年再會諸生面

諸君各自顧前程．好向靈山勤修煉

indeed, there're files of this oracle poem on the internet, like:

[image]

[image]

if you compare part i, you can find that some characters are different.

my opinion: verses are in sequence in part i, predicting events of 1930s - 1940s

then, verses are **not** in sequence in part ii, at least the first half. predicting events from 1949 to 2033?

again, just my ideas, have fun :)

Comment: I can't get past 中山 (which I suppose refers to Sun Yat-sen). I think I need a 3-week holiday to figure out all of this.