# Could this kind of a component-based null cipher be possible in Chinese?

Tags: characters, traditional-characters, radicals, cipher

I'm writing a story set partially in historic China, and it involves a network of secret agents who seek to communicate over the mail in innocuous-looking letters. So I need a description of a pen-and-paper cipher that works for the Chinese language and (traditional) writing system. The story is not ultimately about the language or the cipher, it is just an element that I want to describe accurately.

For the plot I need to use a [null cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_cipher); a way to conceal the secret message in a large amount of regular text by interspersing the secret stuff with lots of random stuff that together looks like it is about something different entirely.

In alphabetical scripts that would work by taking every n'th word, or every n'th letter, and putting them behind each other. This example from Wikipedia:

> HE GOT A GOOD HEART. SHOULD YOU BE HAVING PROBLEMS BE ASSURED THAT WHEN YOU HIT THE STREETS...

Taking every 5th word:

> HE SHOULD BE HIT

I'm considering, for this story, to say that this particular cipher mixed and matched components. That is to say, if the agent wanted to encrypt "steal", 偷; he would find another character starting with 人 (e.g. 仔) and another character ending with 俞 (e.g. 瑜), and write some text between to make it flow as a sentence. Then he'd just need to do so in a regular manner; let's say picking the first component of every 3rd character, then the second component of every 5th character, and maybe some extra cases for characters with even more components. Another agent who reads the text can read it selectively and get the secret message.

That is the level of explanation I'd use in the story; so the question is basically whether that, on the surface, looks feasible. I'm not going to write any actual ciphered text. I just don't want to do disrespect to any speaker of Chinese who comes across the story when I eventually put it online.

Rather than invent my own, I would have used an actual historic cipher, but they seem hard to find. The only one I could find attested is a [grille cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grille_%28cryptography%29). That too is a null cipher, but it operates on the level of whole characters; and I presume that hiding the entire word "steal" in a text would be more suspicious than just hiding its components. Plus using components I can use it in a scene where someone explains the Chinese script itself, for a nice little educational bonus.

Comment: [藏頭詩](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-tw/%E8%97%8F%E9%A0%AD%E8%A9%A9) or [嵌字文](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-tw/%E5%B5%8C%E5%AD%97%E6%96%87) are common in Chinese.

Comment: @Nobody Very helpful, thank you very much!

Comment: That's a rather obvious way to hide a message, though. Therefore it's not secure.

Comment: One thing you may want to note is sending mail was a rather difficult task in ancient China as there was no postal service for a very long time. Only the government had the facilities of sending mail. Civilians could only send mail via couriers in general.

Comment: @fatpenguin The setting is the 1700s, and the mail is pretending to be the communication of a very rich merchant and his associates. :) I think in terms of logistics it is feasible.

Comment: Okay, why would a very rich merchant be a spy (presumably working for a foreign country)? What's in it for him?

Comment: @fatpenguin That's what my windy plot is for to explain, and the story is 107 thousand words long at the moment :)

Comment: Just a quick reminder that rich mechants usually would buy into the government by donating a sizable sum of money. It's usually very good to have power on your side and can save a lot of trouble.

Comment: @fatpenguin It's not the government they're scheming against :) In any case, I am thinking more about the linguistic stuff for this question. One possible weakness I've found in further reading is that the phonetic component is sometimes shared among only few alternative characters so they may still be suspicious in isolation...

Comment: @KeizerHarm Its totally up to you what to write, I only mention this because you seem interested in historical accuracy: merchants were viewed very poorly in old china, like bums leeching off society.  Only slaves and performers//brothels were viewed as lower,  and regular working class and farmers would have been more respected in the general eye.  Just keep in mind when writing a rich merchant role back then, its a tricky thing to portray casually as a spy, a person that already felt suspicious and hated, you might need a hiding in plain sight plot to be accurate.  :)

Answer (score 0):

try “拆字”, or “離合”, the traditional methods to “cipher” characters

[What words exist that come from deconstructed characters?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/30227/what-words-exist-that-come-from-deconstructed-characters/30228#30228)

> a radical-based null cipher be possible in Chinese?

**no**. btw, it should be “component (部件)-based”

> involves a network of secret agents who seek to communicate over the mail

well, . . .  a rant, or query here: the mail delivery “system” in the past is, quite slow. it may take weeks, or months to send a mail. no organisation would survive with such communication speed.

have fun :)

Comment: Well, there was "飛鴿傳書".

Comment: @Nobody, plus 魚雁 

Comment: Also, getting stopped at a border of a territory to enter another , just to deliver your mail could get quite interesting over time haha.

Comment: I've always called components 偏旁, so I'm a bit surprised by 部件 here.  Are they both the same thing?

Comment: @Becky李蓓, “Are they both the same thing?” **no** radical (部首) normally refers to 214 radicals used in 康熙字典. or, 540 radicals used in 說文解字. **radical should be used for indexing only**

Comment: @Becky李蓓, in recent decades, people decompose a han character into component (部件), it’s not yet finalised, “根據中央研究院文獻處理實驗室的統計，所有的基本部件總數為1316個”, there’re thousands components used in han chinese. the total numbers varied, depends on who / where did it, including oracle bone script / bronze script, or not. that depends on who / where did it  here’s a wiki page, have a look: <https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hant/漢字部件#:~:text=正體字計441部件、簡化字計367部件%E3%80%82>

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues that I can think of. Take your example of 偷. How would the recipient know that the character 仔 is the one to start with, and not any other ones? How would he tell that he ought to end with 瑜 and not some other character?

I think a grille cipher is more doable.

Comment: Counting. The algorithm could be simply to combine the first component of characters 1, 6, 11... with the second component of characters 3, 8, 13... it also can be much more complicated; special signs could change the order, maybe one needs to read the page diagonally, etc